# Exception on C# while trying to do OCR example

Tags: c#, ocr

I am trying OCR application on C# with CnetSDK. I have an exception that says

> "threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral."

I tried many things as suggested on similar posts online but nothing seems to work. Can someone please let me know if they have an idea?

```
        // Create an OCR Engine instance.
        OcrEngine OCRLibrary = new OcrEngine();

        // Set the absolute path of tessdata.
        OCRLibrary.TessDataPath = "Desktop:/tessdata/";

        // Set the target text language you want to recognize.
        OCRLibrary.TextLanguage = "eng";

        // Recognize text from image file.
        string Imagetext = OCRLibrary.PerformOCR(@"Desktop:/driving.jpg");
        System.Console.WriteLine(Imagetext);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you share some of the things you have tried?

That error looks like it's trying to reference one of the system.web dll's, is your project Framework or Core? On the CnetSDK website, it does say that it's compatible with .Net Framework versions 4.0 or above.

[image]

Check that your project is a .Net Framework > 4.0 project

System.Web is not part of .net core, so won't be able to use it. https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/838

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for the compatibility mention. I just changed the compability to .NET framework and it worked.

Comment: that's great, glad it worked! please click the checkmark (below the voting buttons) to select it as the answer to your question. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure. Thank you so  much. Sorry, I have been active on stack overflow recently so.